# How to Wake Computers For SSH and Remote Desktop Services?

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, sleep

I have a mix of Mac, Linux and Windows computers. I love being able to SSH into them and launch a remote desktop client, so that I can pretty much access all of my computers from one. The only problem is, SSH doesn't work on any of these OS's unless you prevent the computers from entering sleep mode.

While researching a solution it appears that there are a couple decent programs, but I've only come across platform-specific solutions. I want to do this away from my LAN as well, if I'm at a friends house. Does anyone else have a setup like this successfully set up?

Comment: On the same network you could use a wake on lan packet in order to wake up your computer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN

Comment: @DrNoone You can use it from outside a local network as well. See my 3rd comment.

Comment: [Access Your Computer Anytime and Save Energy with Wake-on-LAN](http://lifehacker.com/348197/access-your-computer-anytime-and-save-energy-with-wake-on-lan)